# stackrel and beamer

Tags: beamer

I want to put a question mark above an equal sign, but I need the question mark to appear BEFORE the equal sign:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\visible<1->{$
    X
    \stackrel{?}
             {\visible<2->{=}}
    Y
  $}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, in the code above the question mark appears not above the equal sign, but at the upper right corner.  I also tried using \stackbin instead, and the question mark now appears to the left of the equal sign.

What is the correct way to do this?  THANKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force the bace of the `\stackrel` to keep the `\mathrel` status:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

$
    X
    \stackrel{?}{\mathrel{\visible<2->{=}}}
    Y
$


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note that if you omit the `\mathrel` you get an error

```
! Limit controls must follow a math operator.
\stackrel  #1#2->\mathrel {\mathop {#2}\limits 
                                               ^{#1}}
l.14 \end{frame}
                
?
```

If you scroll past that then, as you comment in the question a PDF gets made with the ? misplaced to the right, however after any error the PDF is not intended to be usable, just a possible debugging aid, so when asking it is better to ask about the error message rather than whatever random output Tex made if you scroll past the error.

I didn't trace exactly what the interaction with beamer was here but `\visible`, `\only` and friends are rather complicated constructs generating multiple partial pages. The error indicates `\stackrel` is expecting a standard math construct so wrapping everything back in `\mathrel` was an "educated guess".

Comment: Thanks @carlisle.   In a few words could you explain why this works?

Comment: @underflow words added